# What is the alternate for clearApplicationUserData() from PackagerManager class in android?

Tags: java, android, android-11, android-developer-api

I have a requirement for clearing application user data and cache data for provided package name. Previously I was using clearApplicationUserData(), deleteApplicationCacheFiles() methods from PackageManager class. But now both are deprecated or hidden (@hide) in android 11. What's the alternative?

Below is my previous way of doing it -

```
 PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
 //observer is ->IPackageDataObserver
 pm.clearApplicationUserData(packageName, observer);
```

and

```
PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
//observer is ->IPackageDataObserver
pm.deleteApplicationCacheFiles(packageName, observer);
```

What would be the alternate solution for the same? I know there are methods like -

```
(mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager).clearApplicationUserData()
//for clearing current application user data
```

and

```
mContext.getCacheDir().deleteRecursively() 
//for clearing current application cache data
```

But in my case, it is another application and I will provide the package name.

I was reading about [clearApplicationUserData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#clearApplicationUserData(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.OnClearApplicationUserDataListener)) from DevicePolicyManager class, but not sure how it works. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Hi @Bajrang Hudda, I have the exact same situation as yours, did you find your solution to this?

Comment: We don't have any alternative so far, you can not delete any App's data without user permission, and Google doesn't want that so no Public APIs as well. But the same you can achieve this by using a Java SDK Library (java_sdk_library is to make a Java library that implements optional platform APIs to apps.) where you can keep your hidden (clearApplicationUserData()) APIs and call this method from Product partition APPs. - https://source.android.com/docs/setup/about/android-10-release#java_sdk_library